# How can I change the chrome profile numbers?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, mac

I want to change the numbers for the different chrome profiles on my computer (Default, Profile 1, Profile 2, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

The renaming method changes periodically with new releases of Chrome.
For the moment, the profiles are ordered alphabetically, so renaming them
changes the order.

To rename:

- Click your avatar icon
- Click on the Settings icon next to "Other profiles" to display all the profiles
- For each profile to be renamed, click its three-points menu and select "Edit"
- If the profile is not the current, a new Chrome instance will open,
  with the profile details
- Change the profile name. You may then close this Chrome instance.

Note that if you have for example Persons 2 and 3 and that you would like to
swap their names, this would require renaming "Person 2" to "Person 10",
then "Person 3" renamed to "Person 2", finally "Person 10" renamed to
"Person 3".

Answer (score 0):

I'm using brave browser and to change profile order just change alphabetically. If you want that profile to be last, the prefix it with `z`.

Example after

- abcProfile
- myProfile
- zSomething